# Transfer function of capacitor and resistor connected in series and one resistor connected in parallel with the capacitor

Tags: signal-processing, transfer-function, laplace-transform, digital-filter

I have been trying to derive the transfer function H(s) of the circuit diagram.

[image]

I know how to derive CR circuit, but I'm stock on connecting another resistor with the capacitor. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Ask yourself (looking into the circuit) if Vout will be equal to zero for s=0 (thats what your transfer function tells us).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** - you consider the potential divider formed by \$X_C\$ || \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ hence: -

$$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = \dfrac{R_2}{R_2 + R_1|| X_C} = \dfrac{R_2}{R_2 + \frac{R_1}{1+sCR_1}}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you, it works out perfectly!